# Where to put a web worker file in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

HTML5 Web Workers usually depend on external scripts using `importScripts()`. Where should such scripts go under Rails 4, so that they get minified normally as per the assets pipeline, and yet still work correctly?

There are some problems when working with the asset pipeline that need to be addressed:

1. The external scripts, if placed under `vendor/assets`, are not processed by the asset pipeline by default (which wasn't the case in Rails 3).
2. If the scripts are placed under `app/assets`, they need to be included in `application.js` in order to be processed. However, worker files should not be included in the combined output (i.e. `application-[digest].js`).
3. If the scripts are included into the assets config, then the resulting files would include a digest in their file name. To load the worker, one needs to give the browser its path (e.g. `new Worker('myWorker.js')`. How would we find out the path? (I tried `asset_path`, but it didn't work).
4. Just like in 3, workers need to reference other files by name when calling `importScripts()`. How would we find out the path to load?

Comment: I always end up with my workers and imports in the `/public` folder but I must say i am not very happy with this approach

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here from Google - you can use [Inline Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers).

Inline Workers

What if you want to create your worker script on the fly, or create a self-contained page without having to create separate worker files? With Blob(), you can "inline" your worker in the same HTML file as your main logic by creating a URL handle to the worker code as a string:

```
var blob = new Blob([
    "onmessage = function(e) { postMessage('msg from worker'); }"]);

// Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  // e.data == 'msg from worker'
};
worker.postMessage(); // Start the worker.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to convention (which isn't so popular) it should go to `vendor/assets`. To be precise:

- `app/` everything that is strictly bound to this particular app
- `lib/` all code that is written by you but isn't bound to your application (can or will be extracted to separate gem)
- `vendor/` all third-party code

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the convention is actually not of use here. I've updated my question to clarify the real issue.